# How can I set the solution of gurobi to be a multiple of 10 instead of all integers?

Tags: modeling, python, integer-programming, gurobi

For example, the solution for gurobi has two solutions, as follows: [10,20,50,70] [55,79,30,80] I only want to output solutions that contain only multiples of 10. The sample example as follow:

```
m = Model()
R = list(range(0,6)) 

# Adding variables
z = m.addVars(6, lb=1, ub=100, vtype=GRB.INTEGER)

m.addConstr(z.prod([1,1,1,1,1,1]) == 100, name="")

m.setObjective(z.prod([1,1,1,1,1,1]), sense=GRB.MAXIMIZE)
m.update()
```

This program has many solutions, But I just want to output the solution for multiples of 10,like`[10,10,20,30,20,10]`.
Please tell me how do I get the solution.Thank you very much!

Comment: Here is a simple change of variable. Set the domain of a variable x as (non-negative) integers. Use 10x instead of just x to define the model. Solve for x. Then, 10x is your answer.

Comment: I can achieve results with the method you mentioned. But I have another question,If I want to use the elements of the list as the range of the solution, like``` list1 = [10,20,50,60,30]```,and the elements of the solution must belong to the elements of the list.How should this be achieved?

Comment: Best is to use a binary variable associated with each element of the list and then do the same thing Qurious Cube said.